# How to install Valgrind on debian 6 ARM processor?

Tags: debian, g++

Title says it all. This file doesn't appear in 'apt-cache search'.

My **sources.list**:

> deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian squeeze main non-free contrib

How do I get this installed? Do I have to build from source?

Comment: Have you ran `apt-get update` which you should if you have just changed the `sources.list` file?

Comment: yes. definitely. yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Debian only packages `valgrind` (as of 1:3.6.0~svn11254+nmu1) for `amd64`, `i686` and `powerpc`](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/valgrind).

Comment: Gah. Ok. Looks like it's DIY time.

Comment: Just get the source and build it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

No binary valgrind packages are available for arm apparently.  You'll have to build it yourself with the following command:

> apt-get -b source valgrind

If that fails, look at the output and make sure you have met all dependencies.  If not, `sudo apt-get install` those dependencies and try again.